# Spring external config file does not load when start by systemd

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, systemd

I am developing and testing an Spring boot based java application.

I have the external config file "application.yml" stored in "config" folder which locates side-by-side with the corresponding jar file ("nlp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar") in the deployment server ( as per "[24.3 Application property files](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.0.M2/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties)")

and this is my "application.yml" file

```
---
 params:
   trustStorePath: config/client-truststore.jks
   trustStorePassword: wso2carbon
   keyStorePath: config/wso2carbon.jks
   keyStorePassword: wso2carbon
   defaultType: JKS
---
server:
   port: 9763
---
```

this works perfect as long as I start the application manually:

```
java -jar nlp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

however, when I try to start the application by systemd command:

```
sudo systemctl start  nlp.service
```

the application starts up, yet the config file "application.yml" located in the "config" folder is not loaded

this is my "nlp.service" file

```
[Unit]
Description=NLP Service

[Service]
User=wjz
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /home/wjz/nlp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

so, what is the problem? did I missed anything?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you should try to point option `"WorkingDirectory"` in your service.
For example, if your app is located in `/home/wjz/nlp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` and `application.yml` is located in `/home/wjz/config` so `WorkingDirectory=/home/wjz/`